# Need to disable an Apache site for users temporarily

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've got a site that's the back-end of a system that we have designed. normally, we go to different venues and connect the the back-end system over the internet and carry on.

We now have to go to a venue that is literally in a field and has no internet access whatsoever. I have got the system running on a local machine, no problem, but I want to make the main site on the internet unavailable for users, but give them a message telling them what has happened.

At the moment I've got a .htaccess in the root:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/offline.php [R,L]
```

Which half works, but browsers don't like it:

> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.

To recap, I want *any* URL entered:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/dir1/
http://www.example.com/dir1/?area=value
etc.
```

to end up at

```
http://www.example.com/offline.php
```

Any ideas?

thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that your rewrite rule needed an exclude parameter for offline.php.  Otherwise it was trying to redirect all pages in that domain including offline.php - thus the infinite loop Firefox was warning you of.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offline\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/offline.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

For more information, check out the solution described at "[.htaccess and mod_rewrite (redirects) Explained](http://webseodesign.com/blog/2006/04/modrewite-redirects-all-site-pages-to.html)".

> **Redirecting all your pages to one:**
>
> This special rewrite is useful when a
>   you need to close a site (permanently
>   or for maintenance) and send the
>   traffic from all the pages to a
>   special page that explains the current
>   situation. This example excludes
>   stylesheets, jpg and gif images from
>   the redirect, so you can still use our
>   "look and feel" on the special pages.
>   See my [Mod_rewite Redirects All Site
>   Pages To One](http://webseodesign.com/blog/2006/04/modrewite-redirects-all-site-pages-to.html) post for some more on
>   this one.

Comment: Good answer. It basically changes my viewpoint from "Change everything" to "Change everything that isn't the final destination that I want". 

I changed it slightly to use code 302 as The site will be going back up once we've finished in the field.

Cheers.

Comment: To do the rewrite a few miliseconds faster, you can write  -------
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/offline.php [L,NC,R=301] -------
^ means start of a string. This will always be true and will not check (.*) the regex condition until the end

Comment: An other neaty feature is to get only acces from a certain ip or subnet by adding ------------ RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.255\.123\.255$ --------- before or after the first RewriteCond.